# epimorphisms of Lie groups send unipotent elements to unipotent elements.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $f:G\to H$ be a surjective morphism of Lie groups. Suppose $g\in G$ is a unipotent element, namely $Ad_g:Lie(G) \to Lie(G)$ is a unipotent transformation of Lie algebras(the only eigenvalue of is one). Now I wonder how to show that $df(g)\in H$ is also unipotent.

My attempt: Let $w\in Lie(H)$ be a eigenvector of $Ad_{f(g)}$, say $Ad_{f(g)}(w)=rw$. Since $f$ is an epimorphism of Lie groups, I remember that $df$ is surjective as well and assume $df(v)=w$. So we have

$$Ad_{f(g)}(df(v))=r df(v).$$

I wish to somehow conclude from here that

$$Ad_g(v)=rv$$

and since $g$ is unipotnent we have $r=1$. But how? Or are there any other approaches.

Comment: The key ingredient you might want is the Lie-Kolchin theorem. Then just put your element into a unipotent subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any Lie group morphism $f\colon G\to H$ the conjugation map $C_g\colon h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$ satisfies the identity
$$f\circ C_g = C_{f(g)}\circ f.$$
Differentiating this leads to a similar formula for the adjoint map
\begin{equation}\label{1}\tag{*}
df\circ\mathrm{Ad}_{g} = \mathrm{Ad}_{f(g)}\circ df.
\end{equation}
Hence if $X$ is an eigenvector of $\mathrm{Ad}_{g}$ and $df(X)$ is nonzero, then $df(X)$ is an eigenvector of $\mathrm{Ad}_{f(g)}$ with the same eigenvalue.

The same is true also for generalized eigenvectors: Suppose $(\mathrm{Ad}_{g}-\lambda\cdot \operatorname{id})^nX=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and eigenvalue $\lambda$. The binomial expansion of the operator $(\mathrm{Ad}_{g}-\lambda\cdot \operatorname{id})^n$ is
$$(\mathrm{Ad}_{g}-\lambda\cdot \operatorname{id})^n = \sum_{k=0}^n(-\lambda)^k\binom{n}{k}\mathrm{Ad}_g^k.$$
Repeated application of formula \eqref{1} then shows that
$$(\mathrm{Ad}_{f(g)}-\lambda\cdot \operatorname{id})^n(df(X)) = df\Big((\mathrm{Ad}_{g}-\lambda\cdot \operatorname{id})^nX\Big) = df(0) = 0,$$
so if $df(X)$ is nonzero, then it is a generalized eigenvector of $\mathrm{Ad}_{f(g)}$ with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Decomposing the Lie algebra $\mathrm{Lie}(G)$ as a direct sum of the generalized eigenspaces of the map $\mathrm{Ad}_g$ then shows that the spectrum of $\mathrm{Ad}_{f(g)}$ restricted to the image of $df$ is a subset of the spectrum of $\mathrm{Ad}_g$. In particular, if $f$ is surjective and $\mathrm{Ad}_g$ unipotent, then $\mathrm{Ad}_{f(g)}$ is also unipotent.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you wrote. the only part you used the subjectivity of f is the subjectivity of $df$? Is that correct?

Comment: In addition, why do you have to go to the generalized eigenvectors? The ordinary eigebvectors not enough?

Comment: Yes, the surjectivity of df is enough. Considering eigenvectors shows that the spectrum of $\mathrm{Ad}_g$ is contained in the spectrum of $\mathrm{Ad}_{f(g)}$.  However eigenvectors don't necessarily span the full Lie algebra $\mathrm{Lie}(G)$, e.g. when the linear map has a matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. So a priori some non-eigenvector could be mapped to an eigenvector with a different eigenvalue. However generalized eigenvectors span the full space, so there is no room for this to happen.

Comment: It is false that $Ad_{f(g)}$ restricted to the image of $df$ has the same spectrum as $Ad_g$. The reason is that the images of some of the eigenvectors under $df$ could be zero.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Good point! I indeed overlooked the fact that $df(X)$ might get mapped to zero. So instead of equality there is only an inclusion, but fortunately the correct one.

Comment: Now it is correct, although you are proving more than the question asks for: It is much easier to check that if $N$ is a nilpotent endomorphism of a vector space $V$, then for each $N$-equivariant epimorphism $V\to W$, $N$ descends to a nilpotent endomorphism of $W$. You do not even need finite dimension for this.